# How to match only the first number in a string and not the complete one?

Tags: php

I currently have an issue with my code:

```
           setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE"); //only necessary if the locale isn't already set
           $date = new DateTime(helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array(
               'date' => $event->start,
               'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i',
               'timezone' => 'UTC'
           )));

           $date_scn = new DateTime(helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array(
               'date' => $event->end,
               'format' => 'H:i',
               'timezone' => 'UTC'
           )));

           echo '<div id="my-id" class="uk-modal"><div class="uk-modal-dialog"><a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a><div style="font-weight: 400;font-size:18px;padding-bottom: 10px;">text 1</div><hr><br/>';

           echo '<span style="font-weight: 400;">1. text: </span>'.helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array('date' => $event->start, 'format' => 'l, j. F Y, H:i','timezone'=>'UTC')), ' - ', helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array('date' => $event->end, 'format' => 'H:i', 'timezone'=>'UTC')).'</span><br>';


             $cnt = 2; // start the text to count at two as the first one is already defined above

             $raw_amount = object('com://site/ohanah.controller.ticket_type')->ohanah_event_id($event->id)->render(array('event' => $event));

             $filtered_output = strip_tags($raw_amount);

             $filtered_numbers = array_filter(preg_split("/\D/", $filtered_output)); // this line causes the problem
             $first_occurence  = reset($filtered_numbers);

             $filtered_amount = $first_occurence - 1; // subtract 1 from $filtered_output as it is always one more

             for($i=0;$i<$filtered_amount;$i++) { // loop
                 $date->add(new DateInterval('P1W')); //add one week

                 $formatted_time = strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y, %H:%M", $date->getTimestamp());
                 $formatted_time_scnpart = strftime("%H:%M", $date_scn->getTimestamp());
                 // This is the modal
                echo '<span style="font-weight:400;">'.$cnt++.'. '.'Termin: '.'</span>';
                echo '<span>'.$formatted_time.' - '.$formatted_time_scnpart.'</span>';
                echo '<br/>';
              }
              echo '</div></div>';
```

I already commented the line with the problem ( `// this line causes the problem` )

**How this code works:**
`$raw_amount` outputs html with some comments, I am filtering this unnecessary tags with: `$filtered_output = strip_tags($raw_amount);`.

This goes to my line that causes the issues:

```
 $filtered_numbers = array_filter(preg_split("/\D/", $filtered_output));
```

and after that I remove `1` from the output. I do this because the output of `$first_occurence` is `1` too much (because of the way I import the data into it.)

**So whats the problem?**
My  `$filtered_numbers` would match `987654321` but it only should match the first one, in this case the `9`. Maybe I should also add that the string I need to look in the `$raw_output` is always inside a `<strong>` tag, maybe this helps. So can this be done without matching the whole numbers?

Output of `$filtered_output`, this is dynamically generated according to different events.:

```
            if (typeof Koowa === 'object' && Koowa !== null) {
                if (typeof Koowa.translator === 'object' && Koowa.translator !== null) {
                    Koowa.translator.loadTranslations({"KLS_OHANAH_TICKET_GET":"Tickets beziehen","KLS_OHANAH_PAY_OFFLINE":"Buchung absenden","KLS_OHANAH_PAY_WITH_PAYPAL":"Mit PayPal bezahlen","KLS_OHANAH_TICKET_PAY":"Kurs bezahlen"});
                }
            }

            example1
                        example2
            Persons

                event - 5 x 15 min

                1241,2423€

0
1
2

                event - 4 x 78 min (example)

                1241241,2423€

0
1
2
```

Comment: Can you share the raw_amount html? and show the bit you're trying to capture?

Comment: @SimonR I added the `$filtered_output`, as the `$raw_output` is way to long.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here? Remove the very first number from `$filtered_output`? Can you give us a very simple example of what `$filtered_output` is and what `$filtered_numbers` should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) will take an input such as `'13 lskjha12 jsdh 3445'` and return an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 12
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => 3445
)
```

The call to [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will strip all the empty elements and return this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [7] => 12
    [13] => 3445
)
```

If (as I understand your question) you only want the first digit of each of these numbers, then the easiest way is to use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$filtered_numbers = array_map(function ($s) { return substr($s, 0, 1); }, array_filter(preg_split('/\D/', $filtered_output)));
```

for my example text this will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [13] => 3
)
```

If you just want the first digit from the first result, then you can use

```
$filtered_numbers = array_filter(preg_split('/\D/', $filtered_output));
$filtered_numbers = substr($filtered_output[0], 0, 1);
```

Comment: And thats what I want to prevent. I just want the 1, and nothing else. It should always be just one number and nothing more.

Comment: If you just want the first digit from the first result my edit should give you that.